# Low pass butterworth filter in Matlab for PPG

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter

I have implemented a pulse oximeter on FPGA and I am collecting the data at `sampling rate = 115200`. So when I plot the data in Matlab I get the following waveform:

[image]

I would like to set up a simple low pass filter to filter out the noise.So the filtered data looks something like this:

[image]

How do I design this filter? How do I determine the cutoff frequency for butterworth filter (`[b,a] = butter(n,Wn)`)?

```
W1=0.5/60;  % lower cutoff 
W2=4/60;    %higher cutoff
[b,a]=butter(2,[W1,W2]); % Bandpass digital filter design 
h = fvtool(b,a); % Visualize filter
low_pass_data1 = filtfilt(b,a,data); % applying filter to our data
```

The above mentioned algorithm works and I got it from the internet but I don't know how it works? There is no mention of the sampling rate in the above algorithm and yet it works! I don't even know if it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are designing a digital filter, the sampling rate is irrelevant. A digital filter takes a stream of values and outputs a stream of values, it has no chance of knowing at what rate they were taken, nor would it matter.

Therefore, frequencies in digital filters are always relative. Actually, the help of `butter` explains it:

> The cutoff frequency  Wn must be 0.0 < Wn < 1.0, with 1.0 corresponding to half the sample rate.

Therefore, if your natural sampling rate is 115200 Hz and you want to cut off at, I don't know, 10 kHz, then the frequency to pass to butter is 10000/(115200/2) = 0.1736.

In case you wonder why it is half the sampling rate: with a sampling rate of Fs, we can see the frequency content in [-Fs/2,Fs/2] (due to Shannon-Nyquist), therefore half the sampling rate is the highest frequency that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, but in the above algorithm: What exactly is `W1=0.5/60;  % lower cutoff  W2=4/60;    %higher cutoff`? Where did `0.5/60` and `4/60` come from?

Comment: try to plot the `FFT` of your signal. Based on that plot you can tell which are the important frequencies in your signal and where you should use a cutoff.

Comment: The concrete values were probably chosen according to the application that was underlying the example you found. Sometimes you know from your application which frequencies you can filter out. If you don't, you'll have to inspect the spectrum by hand to see where are the relevant parts and which parts can be filtered out (try an STFT for instance).

Comment: Thank you for your input. Can you just show me how can design a simple low pass filter to reduce the noise in the output. I am not so good with filter design.

Comment: To design a low-pass filter use `[b,a] = butter(n,w);` where `n` is the filter order and `w` is the cut-off frequency. I cannot tell you how to choose your cut-off frequency since it depends on your data. You can use an STFT to look at your spectrum to find it out. Otherwise, I really suggest you try a couple of values to get a feeling for what it does and what it looks like. You'll get a trade-off between denoising and lost information about peaks etc. (both more if `w` lower). There is no general rule since it depends on the data...